# Getting error while npm install on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ubuntu, npm-install

I got error while npm install errors like:

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     /home/trapti/meetings/npm-debug.log
UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY requirejs@^2.1.0

what should i do?

Comment: you should include this line with your support request.

Comment: means i can not understand.

Comment: How to change permission from debug.log file, in debug.log file there are read only permission, so my npm install gives error like please include debug.log file, please tell me

Comment: you should install with sudo. also you should go to npm's github/bug tracker, make support request and show them this line, I guess

Comment: can you tell me the command what you told me like  make support request